# Ogr2ogr encoding utf-8 linux

Tags: php, linux, oracle, ogr2ogr

I have a problem shell command ogr 2 ogr

```
ogr2ogr -f OCI OCI:user_name/password@DATABASE:GAS /opt/imp/ready/Gas.shp -skipfailures -overwrite -lco DIM=2 -lco PRECISION=no -lco SRID=2400000 -lco LAUNDER=YES -lco ADD_LAYER_GTYPE=NO -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=GEOM
```

when I call ogr 2 ogr in shell windows its all ok,
but I call to command in php, in database Armenian and Russian fonts inserting `???????????` hieroglyph.

Comment: Please show your entire query.  The error message has nothing to do with the error in the actual question.  Most likely, we can find a way to rewrite your query to avoid the need to put `LIMIT` in that subquery.

Comment: The title of this question is not useful (i.e. in search engines).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have below line at the top of PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php